# #CSS Wrapper does not recognise content

Tags: html, css, height, wrapper

Since last week I am again trying to make a website after an absence of about 2 years. It went pretty well until I noticed that when I minimize the browser, the content does not stay in the wrapper.
I have been looking for solutions on this website and on google but I cant seem to find the right one. Most solutions mention problems with #float and overflow but I do not use float (hope that this is not the problem) and I have been playing with the overflow but I cant get it to work.

Below you can find the CSS and HTML code I used.

The HTML:

```
 <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="content">

            <div id="header">

                <div id="logo">
                <img src="style/images/logo.gif" width="184" height="73" alt="logo" />
                </div>

                <div id="menu">
        <ul id="navlist">
                      <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">1</a></li>
                      <li>2</li>
                      <li>3</li>
                      <li>4</li>
                      <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="main">

                Title

                subtitle

            </div>

            <div id="footer">

                <div id="left_banner">



                </div>

                <div id="right_banner">



                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

and the CSS

```
html, body, ul, li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
background:url(images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
} 

#content {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 780px; 
    height: 100%;
    border-left:#fd5d78 4px solid;
    border-right:#fd5d78 4px solid;
}

#header {
    position:relative;
    height:120px;
}

#logo {
    position:absolute;
    right:43px;
    top:37px;
}

#menu {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:58px;
}



#main {
    position:relative;
    left:25px;
    top:35px;
    width:730px;
    height:320px;
}

#footer {
    position:relative;
    width:730px;
    left:25px;
    top:70px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    clear:both;
}

#left_banner {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:349px;
    height:134px;
    border:#fd5d78 2px solid;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#right_banner {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:349px;
    height:134px;
    border:#fd5d78 2px solid;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Thanks a mil for your help.

Comment: I put this in a jsfiddle and I am not sure I see what the problem is.  I put a border on the wrapper and everything stays inside it.  What do you mean by "minimize the browser"?

Comment: I see it now.  I needed a background image to duplicate.  display:block on the #wrapper will fix it (like jsuissa mentioned).  http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/LC7TP/

Comment: Thanks for your help, maybe i am doing something wrong but the display:block is not working for me... Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Maybe if you explain again what you are seeing that is bad.  I tried this in chrome 18 and IE9 and the content says inside the wrapper fine when I shrink the browser height.  Did you click on my jsfiddle link and still see the problem there?

Comment: Hi Ryan, dump from Chrome with the display:block included in script: http://i46.tinypic.com/2b41me.jpg.   When I open the jsfiddle link i see the following: i46.tinypic.com/rcirnq.jpg.  Does this make sense? hope so :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use floats?  Can the solution use floats?  I have a solution for you if floats is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:block;` to the #wrapper

Comment: Hmm. I tried your code  in Chrome and didn't see an issue. When I downsized in IE9 the red border had gaps as window shrank. Adding display:block fixed this. What browser/platform are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using Chrome and IE9 on Vista. When i look in JsFiddle (http://i46.tinypic.com/rcirnq.jpg) it still does not cover the two boxes.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/LC7TP/)

I know you said you don't use floats, but here is a solution using them.  One of the biggest problems you had was you were setting the two footer banners to absolute positions, which throws off the 100% height on the parent div.  With floats and overflow:hidden you are able to  bring those divs back into the 100% calculation.

I had to make many changes to your css, so take what I have in the jsfiddle as your starting point.